# Coordinate left-right-up-down in C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm making a pan-tilt tracking camera like [this](http://www.raspihub.com/go/22915dbee53280677e518a7c11038176b6c80db9728004e2ff910dca1c4688d7), before control servos, I have to know where object is ( up-left, up-right, down-left, down-right), I've tried

```
            if ( x > 350) {
                move_right();

            }
            else if (x < 290) {
                move_right();

            }
            if ( y > 206) {
                move_up();

            }
            else if ( y < 126) {
                move_down();                 

            }
```

But I think it's looked weird. Is there any method simple like switch statement?? My code is written in C++ and OpeCV libraries

Comment: Is this your actual code? Should the x < 290 case call move_left()?

Comment: yep, I depend on image pixels high and wide

Answer (score 0):

The `switch` statement uses exact values and not inequalities.  It won't be of any use for you.

I don't know if you really need the "else-if".  Also, what happens when `x` is between 290 and 350?

If you can keep the comparison operator the same, you could create a lookup table of .

Comment: I dont need to control servo when object's in between 290 and 350